# Displaying MKMapView to show multiple annotations and current user location at once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotation

I have displayed multiple annotations on the MKMapView, but when I want to display the current user location with the multiple annoations, it jumps to the user location and does not display  all the annotations and the user location on the same screen.

Answer (score 1):

hi you have to set the map view according your annotation coordinate in map region.

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapView
{
if([self.mapView.annotations count] == 0)
    return;

CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

for(DDAnnotation* annotation in mapView.annotations)
{
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);        
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides

region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set region of your mapview according two pins -

```
float maxLat = current_location_latitude;
float maxLon = current_location_longitude;
float minLat = other_location_latitude;
float minLon = other_location_longitude;

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat + minLat) / 2.0, (maxLon + minLon) / 2.0), 1000.0, 1000.0);
region.span.latitudeDelta = MAX(region.span.latitudeDelta, (maxLat - minLat) * 1.20);
region.span.longitudeDelta = MAX(region.span.longitudeDelta, (maxLon - minLon) * 1.20);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```